# redownload all documentation for a package with APT

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, documentation

I've recently installed a fingerprint system for kubuntu, of which part replaces a critical system component(I forget which, but it's important, so I can't use apt reinstall). I used to have one of my configurations modified to also remove all documentation pages in /usr/share/doc/ because for a short while I needed to save space while my 1tb ssd was coming in the mail, and I was using a spare 10gb hdd for the time. I've removed the part of 01_nodoc which removes the documentation, but after running apt update and upgrade, nothing has appeared in the directories. What command could one use to generate the docfiles again without reinstalling everything?

```
Unable to run the command specified. The file or folder /usr/share/doc/fingerprint-gui/Manual_en.html does not exist.
```

Comment: Quite a pickle you've made for yourself. Neither apt nor dpkg can do "partial" reinstalls - it's all or nothing. An apt upgrade will NOT automatically restore missing files. Missing files will often cause dpkg pre-removal scripts to error, aborting the entire queue of apt actions. It's probably easiest to live without manpages (docfiles) until you need them, then reinstall as-needed using dpkg (since you say you cannot use apt).

Comment: is there any way for me to access documentation without a reinstall? is there a tar somewhere containing the documentation and the binary? is there a way to get to the html documentation from the cannonical site?

Comment: Well, sure. Lots of manpages are online several places - start at http://manpages.ubuntu.com. Alternately, you can find source files for most of the packages at launchpad.net.

Comment: I've edited my post to contain the error message, I couldn't find anything for fingerprint-gui in the man archive, is there one for html docs?

Comment: Where did you get the software from? There's nothing called "fingerprint-gui" in the Ubuntu repositories, nor any description including that string. Usually that means you added some non-Ubuntu source to install the software. You would need to look in that source for the package or the docs. It's also not clear what command you are running that gives the error.

Comment: Maybe you could use `apt download` to get the files, then copy them to the correct places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the documentation using the `apt redownload` command. I was skeptical of it working at first, but it does work for many system components, and nothing was lost in the process.